# Retrieve the RDS endpoint after invoking lambda function from cloudformation custom resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I built a lambda function in Python to create an RDS instance using Cloudformation custom resource template.
The lambda and CF code work fine but I am not sure how I can return the endpoint to CF. I don't want to set a while loop within the lambda to look for the endpoint because it isn't very cost-efficient.

What would be the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to use e Cloudformation custom resource to create an RDS instance instead of using directly AWS::RDS::DBInstance https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html ?

Comment: Because I am looking to dynamically create our infrastructure.   I see there is Troposphere which I can use to create CF template.